# TypeGraphQL and Typegoose InputType of Ref array

Tags: graphql, typegraphql, typegoose

I'm having difficulties to find resources which explains how to cope with array of References to objects with TypeGraphQL and Typegoose.

Given the following models:

```
@ObjectType({description: "Blog Tag Model"})
export class BlogTag {

  @Field(() => ID)
  id: number;

  @Field(_type => String)
  @Property({required: true, unique: true, index: true, trim: true })
  name: string;
}

@ObjectType({ description: "Blog post model" })
export class BlogPost {

  @Field(() => ID)
  id: number;

  @Field()
  @Property({required: true})
  title: string;

  @Field()
  @Property({required: true})
  description: string;

  @Field(_type => [BlogTag], {nullable: false})
  @Property({default: [], ref: 'BlogTag'})
  tags: Ref<BlogTag>[];
}


@InputType({ description: "Blog post input" })
export class BlogPostInput implements Partial<BlogPost>{

  @Field()
  @Property()
  title: string;

  @Field()
  @Property()
  description: string;

  // Here is the problem / question
  @Field(_type => [BlogTag], {nullable: false})
  @Property({ref: BlogTag})
  tags: Ref<BlogTag>[];   
}
```

This is the error obtained for this code:

```
CannotDetermineGraphQLTypeError: Cannot determine GraphQL input type for 'tags' of 'BlogPostInput' class. Is the value, that is used as its TS type or explicit type, decorated with
a proper decorator or is it a proper input value?
```

What I want to achieve is to give possibility to `BlogPost` model to store an array of References/ObejctIDs of the `BlogTag` model.

I am new to this framework and I don't know if this is a good practice.
How can I create an InputType which accepts an array of IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a separate `BlogTagInput` with `@InputType` or check the FAQ for some handy yet "doatyourownrisk" workaround:

https://typegraphql.com/docs/faq.html#situations-frequently-arise-where-inputtype-and-objecttype-have-exactly-the-same-shape-how-can-i-share-the-definitions

Comment: Thank you, at the end I couldn't find a better solution so I created a BlogTagInput @InputType and change BlogPost input - tags with:
  @Field(_type => [BlogTagInput], {nullable: 'itemsAndList'})
  @Property({ref: BlogTag})
  tags: BlogTagInput[];